# How do I promote a User to an admin user a controller method and passing in the user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, hyperlink, controller

I have a users index page:

```
<ul>
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<li><%= user.name %> |  <%= link_to "Promote to Admin", :controller => :users_controller, :action => :promote_to_admin(user) %> </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

When I click on the "Promote to Admin" link, I want the user to be promoted to admin by calling the promote_to_admin action in usersController. How do I do it ?

Here is my usersController:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def index
@users = User.all
end


def promote_to_admin
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  user.update_attribute!(:admin, true)

  if user.admin == true
    flash[:success] = "User has been sucessfully promoted to admin"

  else
    flash[:error] = "User could not be promoted to manager"
end
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

this should be like:

```
<li><%= user.name %> |  <%= link_to "Promote to Admin", :controller => :users_controller, :action => :promote_to_admin(:user) %> </li>
```

Please notice:

```
:promote_to_admin(:user)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific please ?

Comment: answer updated.. while calling action, you didn't use `:user` but only `user`, which could be a cause of problem.